# RIA Service add element to list after Data is loaded

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm populating a combobox with data from a ria service, directly from xaml using the DomainDataSource. How do I go about adding a new selected element that says "any"? The combobox is used for filtering.

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" Height="0" LoadedData="countryDomainDataSource_LoadedData" x:Name="countryDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetCountriesQuery">
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                <my:ApplyDataContext />
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
</riaControls:DomainDataSource>
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_Country" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=countryDomainDataSource}" DisplayMemberPath="Country1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest workaround is to insert that element in the domain service, as the returned collection is read only.